# How to check SSL Certificate is type (OV,EV)

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to check SSL Certification type is it OV or EV for domain.

Currently i use this library to fetch certificate data from domain https://github.com/spatie/ssl-certificate

```
$certificate = SslCertificate::download()->forHost('apple.com');
```

for testing purpose i use apple.com domain.

the output is:

[image]
[image]
[image]
How can i understand which type is it OV, EV etc..?

Comment: Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Extended_Validation_certificates): "Extended validation is signaled in a certificate using X.509 v3 extension. Each CA uses a different Object Identifier (OID) to assert extended validation. There is no single OID to indicate extended validation". From that, I'd go to [Firefox](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/EV_Processing_for_CAs#EV_TLS_Capable) and see what they do, as well as Chrome. For DV-only, it might just be that the "Subject" only contains `CN`, not 100% sure.